# How to get list of large intraday movers for that day?

Tags: equities

Is there a source (preferably free :) that provides a list of large intraday (versus pre market) movers for the day you look?  I don't mind getting the list on market close.  I don't need historical data, just data for the day I'm looking.

Answer (score 1):

No Such source which provides you this information. 
You could write a script which periodically downloads the data from source pages/website and which could give you the required information.

Most indices let you download data in excel format. Custom configuration of excel could help you here.

Comment: Yikes, that's not true at all.  I could just scan through large movers and manually filter out the ones for large intraday movements. I was just hoping there was a source that already did that.